# After uncheck still disable - checkbox

Tags: javascript

I need help with this code.

I would like to create a function when I uncheck the second or third checkbox and the first will be still disabled.

Can you help me with some please?

I tried to use if / else or array where I choose variables, but still nothing.*

```js
function toggleCheckboxState(className, diabled) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i)
  {
      checkboxes[i].disabled  = diabled
  }
}
    
document.getElementById('checkme3').onclick = function(e) {
    var diabled  = false
  if(this.checked) {
        diabled = true
  }
    
    toggleCheckboxState('parent', diabled)
}
    
document.getElementById('checkme2').onclick = function(e) {
    var diabled  = false
  if(this.checked) {
        diabled = true
  }
    toggleCheckboxState('parent', diabled)
}

document.getElementById('checkme1').onclick = function(e) {
    var diabled  = false
  if(this.checked) {
        diabled = true
  }

  toggleCheckboxState('child', diabled)
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkme1" class='parent'  value="Yes" />
     first<br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkme2" class='child'  value="No" />
     second<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme3" class='child'  value="No" />
     third<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme4" class='child'  value="No" />
     fourth<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme5" class='child'  value="No" />
     fifth<br>
     
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi, so what is the request exactly? You want to disable checkbox one permanently, that's it?

Comment: I am not sure what behavior your looking for.  Can you explain what you would expect to happen if, for instance, none of the boxes are checked and then I check the checkme3 box?

Comment: You have two different spellings of disabled: "diabled" and "disabled".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkme1" class='parent' value="Yes" />
        first<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkme2" class='child' value="No" />
        second<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkme3" class='child' value="No" />
        third<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkme4" class='child' value="No" />
        fourth<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkme5" class='child' value="No" />
        fifth<br>

    </form>
    </p>



    <script>
        function toggleCheckboxState(className, diabled) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
                checkboxes[i].disabled = diabled
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('checkme3').onclick = function (e) {
            var diabled = false
            if (this.checked || document.getElementById('checkme2').checked) {
                diabled = true
            }

            toggleCheckboxState('parent', diabled)
        }

        document.getElementById('checkme2').onclick = function (e) {
            var diabled = false
            if (this.checked || document.getElementById('checkme3').checked) {
                diabled = true
            }
            toggleCheckboxState('parent', diabled)
        }

        document.getElementById('checkme1').onclick = function (e) {
            var diabled = false
            if (this.checked) {
                diabled = true
            }

            toggleCheckboxState('child', diabled)
        }
    </script>
```

Working example
https://codepen.io/mohseni12345/pen/rNLybLj